# Table view cell disappear when i switch to another page and then back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a table view that you can add and delete cells. I can enter multiple cells and when i go to the next page and then switch back, all of my entries/ cells are erased. Can any one figure this out? Here is my code:

```
@implementation FacePlatesViewController

@synthesize woodGrain;
@synthesize nav, array;
@synthesize EditButton;
@synthesize myTableView, image;
@synthesize cell, string1;
@synthesize myDic, cells, defaults;
@synthesize selectedCell, currentChosenFund;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString * myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cells" ofType:@"plist"];
self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];

}


- (void)addObject:(id)anObject
{
if (anObject != nil)
{
    [cells addObject:anObject];
}
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender 
{




if (self.editing) 
    {
        [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [self.myTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];

    } 

    else 
    {

        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

    }
}

- (void)add
{
    MyDetailViewController * detail = [[MyDetailViewController alloc]init];
    detail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:detail animated:YES];
    [detail.text becomeFirstResponder];
    [detail release];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [cells count];
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [[self cells] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
        [[self myTableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero   
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }  
    //The if block should end here. You should set the cell's label irrespective whether the cell was nil. This is the cause of the issue you are facing.

    cell.textLabel.text = [[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];


    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FirstFolderViewController * first = [[FirstFolderViewController alloc]init];
    first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
    [first release];
}

    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
       toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)targetIndexPath
{
    NSUInteger sourceIndex = [sourceIndexPath row];
    NSUInteger targetIndex = [targetIndexPath row];

    if (sourceIndex != targetIndex)
    {
        [[self cells] exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndex
                          withObjectAtIndex:targetIndex];
    }

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [woodGrain release];
    [myTableView release];
    [EditButton release];
    [nav release];
    [cells release];
    [myTableView release];
    [myDic release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];  
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setWoodGrain:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


@end
```

Thanks :D

Comment: You mean they all vanish or revert to the original set that you read from the file? The latter is to be expected since you don't seem to save the new cells anywhere, so once FacePlatesViewController dies, the cells are gone.

Comment: hey bud, thanks for the help. But im not too sure how to save the cells to a file! Could you please give me a bit more assistance? Thanks

Comment: FacePlatesViewController does not die when a VC is pushed on top of it. And there is no need to save the cells to a file.

Comment: @PengOne2 So what happens, do all cells disappear or they revert to the set in the file? And please clarify how do you "go to the next page and then switch back" - do you do push the new view into the navigation controller then pop it or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually even unloading of the view will be enough to throw away the cells. Try this in your viewDidLoad:

```
if(!cells) {
    NSString * myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cells" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
}
```

(this way you won't be rereading the array every time the view is loaded).

And if you want the added cells to persist between app restarts, you do need to save them somewhere. You can't change the files in the main bundle, but you can write your own file into the Caches folder, which you can get via:

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Write your file into that folder and read the cells from there instead of the main bundle. If you have some pre-defined cells in the main bundle file, you can check if the file in the Caches folder exists when the app starts, and if not, copy the bundle's file into the Caches folder.

Edit: if you do presentModalViewController to get back from the another page, you'll get a fresh copy of FacePlatesViewController, which obviously loads the default cells from the file.
Instead, you should add a "delegate" property to your FirstFolderViewController:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate; //yes, assign, not retain
```

then when presenting FirstFolderViewController do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FirstFolderViewController * first = [[FirstFolderViewController alloc]init];
    first.delegate = self;
    first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
    [first release];
}
```

Then add a method to FacePlatesViewController:

```
- (void) onDoneWithFirstFolderViewController //you can come up with a better name
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and in your FirstFolderViewController, when you are ready to close it, do:

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onDoneWithFirstFolderViewController)]) 
    [delegate onDoneWithFirstFolderViewController];
```

Ironically, if you had implemented the cell persistence in a file, this issue might have been unnoticed (because each new FacePlatesViewController would load an up-to-date cell list), but you would have had a memory leak each time you went between pages.

Comment: hey man thanks for the help, but i added your code, and i cant seem to get it to work still:( im not sure whats wrong? But when i press the tableview cell, it takes me to another page, and then after i press my back button which is on my nav bar on the next page. And when i come back to my table view, all the cells i just added are gone and the table view looks the exact same as it did when i first started the app.

Comment: If you delete a cell, then do your trick with going to another page and back, does the deleted cell reappear? If yes, add NSLog(@"dealloc!"); to your FacePlatesViewController dealloc, NSLog(@"viewDidUnload"); to viewDidUnload, NSLog(@"viewDidLoad") to viewDidLoad, then run the app and see in what sequence these statements show up in the console when you tap a cell and then go back. I'll add the second question as a separate comment.

Comment: Please also describe how you add cells - do you do that in your MyDetailViewController? Then what do you do with the new data - I see you have an addObject method, do you call that? In your addObject you probably need to do call [myTableView reloadData] for the new cell to appear.

Comment: yes i do it in MyDeatailViewController. I press an add button and it takes us to this page, we enter text into a textfield and the new cell is added once we press the save button on MyDetailViewController and the new cell is added that way. And no i can add and delete cells perfectly fine! but when i switch to another page and come back to the table view, the newly added cells are gone!! Only 1 cell is left. it is the cell that i manually put into the tableView via the plist.

Comment: OK, but if you _delete_ that one cell that you have added via plist, then go to another page and back, does the cell reappear or does the table stay empty?

Comment: No, if i delete that cell and switch pages... it comes back when i go back to the table view!

Comment: This means that your cells array gets recreated - please add the NSLog statements as I've described above and see what happens when you go to another page is back.

Comment: ok i added the NSLog's and i found out that the dealloc and viewDidUnload never get called. When the app starts up i get viewDidLoad called. i switch pages, nothing happens, but when i go back to the table view, i get another viewDidLoad.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you are getting a _second_ copy of FacePlatesViewController loaded. To confirm, change the viewDidLoad NSLog to: NSLog(@"viewDidLoad, I am %x", self); (yes, %x, not %@ - %x will print the object's address). Do you get a different address when you first load the app and when you return from another page? If yes, please describe how you return from that another page? I see you do presentModalViewController to go to a FirstFolderViewController, but what do you do to get back? If you make another presentModalViewController, that is your problem (I'll edit the answer for solution)

Answer (score 0):

To me, the problem seems to be related to your code in `ViewWillAppear:` Have you ensured that your cells array is fine when you call `[self.myTableView reloadData];` ?

Also, I noticed `myTableView`. Are you subclassing `UITableViewController` or implementing table delegates? If you are subclassing, the table view reference is named `tableView`.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: um... how could i check to see if my cells array is ok when i call reloadData? And no im not subclassing from UITableViewController. I added this code a while back and i should delete it now.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not subclassing UITableViewController?